# Where do you put the CSRF token in Relay/GraphQL?

Tags: laravel, reactjs, csrf, graphql, relayjs

I am trying to get Relay and GraphQL set up with my Laravel server. I have successfully set Laravel up to serve GraphQL.

In the past, to make ajax calls with jQuery I added the following to my master.blade.php:

```
 <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

and the following to my main.js file:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

My GraphQL endpoint is currently returning token mismatch exception. It seems to me that Relay needs to pass the csrf-token to the server in a similar manner as jQuery.ajax. Where does it go?

Comment: how are you using Relay with graphql-laravel ? I think that it need to be compatible with Relay . opened a issue https://github.com/Folkloreatelier/laravel-graphql/issues/9

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Configure your network layer to append headers to each request:

```js
Relay.injectNetworkLayer(
  new Relay.DefaultNetworkLayer('/graphql', {
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
    },
  })
);
```

The second argument to `Relay.DefaultNetworkLayer` gets passed through to the `init` argument of [`fetch(input, init)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalFetch/fetch#Parameters). See the [Relay Network Layer Guide](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/guides-network-layer.html#default-network-layer) for more information.

Comment: Thanks! So easy! I was stuck thinking that I needed to grab the dom attr('content') without jQuery.

Comment: If you don't want to use jQuery at all, you can get the token using `document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content')`